# Edit parameter reporting option is not showing in firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated firebase analytics and not able to add parameter reporting in firebase console. Option is not showing up in the console. I am an admin to the project. I don't have an idea of this why its not showing up.[image]

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase console, you should reach out to Firebase support directly for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I see the same. Question to Firebase support sent...

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I had the same problem and they got back to me with this article https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209 which replaces custom parameter reporting

Comment: @Moulie415 You are right. They haven't updated their document yet. Have to use custom metrics and dimensions.